# Show this function is always $\geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions

I'm trying to show that:

$$
   1 + \frac{xy}{e^{\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2-2)}} \ge 0, \forall~x,y \in \mathbb{R^2}
$$

But I end up with the following inequality:

$$
   \ln{xy} - \frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2-2) \ge \ln{(-1)}
$$

Which looks like nonsense to me since $xy$ could easily be negative (say $x=-2, y=+2 \rightarrow xy = -4$).

So I'm guessing I'm approaching this in a wrong way. I've also plotted the function and it's indeed $\ge 0, \forall~x,y \in \mathbb{R^2}$ converging to 1 when $x,y \rightarrow \pm \infty$.

Any tips or sources on how to approach the problem (analytically) would be appreciated. <s>Also, why is it that I end up with such a nonsense expression following the initial approach?</s>

**Edit**:

1. I missed a $\frac{1}{2}$ in the denominator, just added it.
2. $\ln{(-1)}$ is not defined in the real numbers, that's what I mean by "nonsense".
3. $\ln{(xy)}$ causes the same issue with $xy<0$.

Comment: $\ln(-1)$ gives a complex number

Comment: Try the case $x=1/\sqrt{2}$, $y=-x$.

Comment: As @Kelenner pointed out, the inequality is false for $y=-x$ and $x$ in the range 0.5 to 0.9.

Comment: What is $\ln -1\quad ?$  Do you mean $\ln(-1)$?

Comment: Yes, of course I mean $\ln{(-1)}$. I just edited.

Comment: Just realized I missed a 0.5 on the denominator, so I updated the expression. I still don't find any couple $x,y$ which yield a value $<0$.

Comment: Try truncating the series expansion of $\exp$ to the first-order term.